# Maven plugin proxying artifacts

Tags: maven, quarkus, maven-extension

I have a Quarkus project and I need to hack one dependency of its extensions, providing my own artifact instead (released at different coordinates). It would be pretty simple using just exclusions and extra dependency in the POM, but Quarkus does some annotation processing on the dependency and has the `groupId:artifactId::classifier` hardcoded in the extension. Rather than hacking the extension, too, which would be rather cumbersome as I'd really prefer to not have to release the extension often, I would like to trick Maven into presenting my dependency as the original one.

Is there a Maven plugin or extension that already does that? I could ofc. combine multiple plugins, so I can imagine using `dependency` plugin to fetch the hacked artifact, rename it and then this plugin I am looking for would prioritize the 'custom' directory over local repository.